# Does Object and Data Input/output streams creates conflict?

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream

I have this client code

```
dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dOut.writeByte(2);  <--when readByte on server gives -84
oos.writeObject(rectangle);
```

if slightly changed

```
dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dOut.writeByte(2);  <--when readByte on server gives 2
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(rectangle);
```

why is this happening? case is similar in `inputstream` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The data will get hopelessly mixed up.

There's no need for this. `ObjectOutputStream` already has all the methods of `DataOutputStream.` You don't need them both.