# Java IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, sockets, executorservice, ioexception

Im trying to implement a basic rpc server in java.

I want to be able to tell the server what operation i want to do and the server should retrieve data from database base on that operation and send it to the client.

Here is the code for more context:

Server:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String operationType;
        int id;
        while (!socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                operationType = in.readUTF();
                if (operationType.equals("Take test!")) {
                    Future future = pool.submit((Callable) () -> {
                        return studentDAO.getTest(1);
                    });
                    Object obj = future.get();
                    objOut.writeObject(obj);
                    pool.shutdown();
                }
                //notifyAllUsers(type);
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                close(socket, in, out, objIn, objOut);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
public void applyChanges(String operation) {
        new Thread(
                () -> {
                    try {
                        if (operation.equals("Take test!")) {
                            out.writeUTF(operation);
                            //objOut.writeInt(1);
                            Test test = (Test) objIn.readObject();
                            System.out.println(test.getTestName());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                        close(socket, in, out, objIn, objOut);
                    }
                }, "applyThread"
        ).start();
    }
```

Error:

```
run:
Client accepted!
java.net.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:417)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:437)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:823)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1035)
true
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1901)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1810)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1304)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1249)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1445)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1196)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1617)
Socket closed
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:365)
    at server.ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

But i get this instead :  An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When debugging, it is always good to log or just print to make sure you know where the client and server are when things go south. Plus include whatever stack trace you get, as it tends to include line numbers.

Comment: Add the following line to the `catch` block in method `run` of the _Server_: `ex.printStackTrace();` Then run your code. Then copy the entire stack trace (to the [system] clipboard). Then [edit] your question and paste the stack trace.

Comment: I forgot... i added full error message.

Comment: I think maybe the problem is with `ObjectOutputStream` and how i coded i just don't know what is it.

Comment: You are calling `pool.shutdown()` after submitting a task.  Any subsequent attempt to submit a task will generate an exception (probably a RejectedExecutionException).  If your server object (which I see implements Runnable) is itself submitted to an ExecutorService, you probably won’t see this exception unless you examine the corresponding Future.  You don’t really need a thread pool at all, since you’re waiting for the Future anyway, effectively making the call to studentDAO.getTest a synchronous call.

Comment: If i understood you right i should just have something like this? `Object obj = studentDAO.getTest(1); objOut.writeObject(obj);`

Comment: @VGR Thank you for you'r advice and additional information. It is good to know it.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I’m suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was...

This is my ClientHandler constructor.

```
public ClientHandler(Socket socket) {
    try {
        this.socket = socket;
        //this.in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        //this.out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        this.objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        this.objIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        this.pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        this.studentDAO = new StudentAccess();
        listOfUsers.add(this);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

I had Data and Object streams on the same socket.
To have more then one of different streams on a socket will create a conflict and hence in my case the error above.

Once i commented out the ones i didn't need it started working just fine.

For more information go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158332/does-object-and-data-input-output-streams-creates-conflict) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170275/creating-2-streams-with-one-socket).

It's a beginner mistake that cost me one full day of time. : - )